# Installing JRuby gems with Mina

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, mechanize, mina

I'm trying to deploy an app on JRuby with Mina, but one gem doesn't install and actually it shouldn't be installed in the first place...

The gem is `unf_ext` and it is a Mechanize dependency. If I SSH to the server and try to install `Mechanize`, it installs without problems and only `unf` installs as a result, not `unf_ext`.

Error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. 

       /home/linkrecover/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.13/bin/jruby extconf.rb  
   NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS. 

      (root) at /home/linkrecover/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8 
     require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065 
      (root) at /home/linkrecover/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1 
      (root) at extconf.rb:1 


   Gem files will remain installed in /var/www/lr/tmp/build-14062262733806/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/unf_ext-0.0.6 for inspection. 
   Results logged to /var/www/lr/tmp/build-14062262733806/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/unf_ext-0.0.6/ext/unf_ext/gem_make.out 
   An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.6), and Bundler cannot continue. 
   Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My Gemfile: https://gist.github.com/davidhq/09d84bc79683b9d3332e

So how to make bundler install everything nicely when run through Mina?

Answer (score 0):

some of your declared gems (*Gemfile.lock* should tell which one) depends on the `unf_ext` gem which uses native C extensions. you will need to somehow avoid that gem (e.g. with a **platform: :mri** just like you did with others) with JRuby. details depend on the problematic gem and how much of it you need, e.g. if it's only for development simply move it to a **group :development** and `bundle --without development`

Comment: Actually the Mechanize gem depends on `unf_ext` ... but when installed on JRuby it shouldn't need that... I think I'm not supposed to move `Mechanize` to `platform: :jruby` because it works on both, just with different dependancies.

Comment: I figured it out... answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `Gemfile.lock` didn't have dependencies for JRuby figured out because I'm using MRI for development. I switched to JRuby locally and ran `bundle install` to generate the correct info in `Gemfile.lock` and commited it... now everything installs fine.